# Akka registration base routing

Tags: akka

I have the following requirement: 
I want to have a router or actor that forwards messages to 0-* actors (destinations).

The destinations register and deregister themselves at the router via registration and deregistration messages (like listeners).

My idea was, to have a Map in a "RoutingActor", which holds the references of the destinations. But if I do implement it this way, I cannot use "AkkaSystem.actorOf(RoutingActor.class)" because I may get different actors, right?

So, what is the correct solution here? I want to build a router/dispatcher which can change the message destinations during runtime from these destination Actors.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'm going to use the Eventbus mechanism now. This appears to be the right pattern for my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a single instance of your routing actor first, giving it a name so that it can be looked up again later elsewhere.  Then later and elsewhere, use `actorFor` instead of `actorOf`:

```
val router = system.actorOf(Props[RoutingActor], "myrouter")
```

Then somewhere else:

```
val router = system.actorFor("/user/myrouter")
router ! msg
```

Or if you are using Akka 2.2:

```
val router = system.actorSelection("/user/myrouter")
router ! msg
```

Answer (score 1):

Use actorFor/actorSelection to find the router actor by path.

Use [Listeners](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.5/#akka.routing.Listeners) to help you implement the router actor functionality.